# After transform.translate my custom button' onPressed does not work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have an issue about transform.translate/transform widgets. My ui is working very well but after i added a button of transform's child, the onPressed is not working.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height,
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          right: 30,
          bottom: 30,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),
                    degOneTranslationAnimation!.value * 100),
                child: Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                      getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation!.value))
                    ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation!.value),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularButton(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 60,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
                    onClick:() => print('tap button'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

the only we need to do is add .call() to the end of the function to be void.
onPressed: ()=>onPressed   to onPressed: ()=>onPressed.call()

Comment: thank you I solved the issue but I am late to write down here... :(